# Oracle Php Login Script

Tags: php, oracle11g, oracle-call-interface

i have created a login script in `php` using `Mysql` database but im trying to mimic the same script using `Oracle 11g` database,my problem is that i can not seem to login no errors are showing on my page or notices,im pretty sure the mistakes are from `SQL statements` here is what i have and i have been following this link [PHP ORACLE MENU](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php)

my login scrip

```
<?php
                if(isset($_POST['login'])){
                    include 'includes/config.php';

                    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
                    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

                    $query = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE uname = '$uname' AND pass = '$pass'");
                    oci_execute($query);

                    $rs = $conn->query($query);
                    $num = $rs->num_rows;
                    $rows = $rs->oci_fetch_array();
                    if($num > 0){
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['uname'] = $rows['uname'];
                        $_SESSION['pass'] = $rows['pass'];
                        echo "<script type = \"text/javascript\">
                                    alert(\"Login Successful.................\");
                                    window.location = (\"admin/index.php\")
                                    </script>";
                    } else{
                        echo "<script type = \"text/javascript\">
                                    alert(\"Login Failed. Try Again................\");
                                    window.location = (\"login.php\")
                                    </script>";
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

i'm trying to learn the oracle php scripting and i need guidance on how  to sort this out thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Is your password stored in plain text? Seems so. 2. It's meaningless to store the password in session variable. 3. `window.location` line does not require `()` 4. You can just use `header("Location: $url");` to redirect instead of JS, which can be disabled by end users.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement looks ok to me. 
If the connection string ($conn) is ok, following code should do the trick.

```
$query = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE uname = '$uname' AND pass = '$pass'");
oci_execute($query);
if( $rows = oci_fetch_array($query) ){
  //... set session variables, login, etc...
}
```

The line

```
if( $rows = oci_fetch_array($query)
```

would just return false if there are no results.